# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.register.register.file.User.getName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

[image]

Can not able to retrieve data from firebase database

I am trying to retrieve username from firebase database, but it is not working

```
String Uid;
String name;//below code is in onCreate()
mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FirebaseUser uid=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Uid=uid.getUid();
            mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Uid);
            User user1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            name =user1.getName();
            userName.setText(name);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
        String name;
        String Uid;
        FirebaseUser uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Uid = uid.getUid();
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(Uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                name = user.getName();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you so much @vikas singh ,it solves app crash :)

Comment: bro i want to store username(name) to a string which i can able to use that string outside addValueListener... i heard that it follows an asynchronous process is there any way to store this into a string and use it outside